# Nodejs exec permission denied when accessing file system

Tags: javascript, node.js

When executing this script

```
      exec(
        `aws --profile ${process.env.PROFILE} s3 cp s3://${BUCKET_NAME}/${lastBackupFile} ./data`,
        (err, stdout, stderr) => {
          if (err || stderr) {
            console.log(stderr);
            console.log(err);
          }

          console.log(stdout);
```

I get this error

```
/bin/sh: 2: ./data: Permission denied
```

I have been trying to `sudo` the f** out of everything but could't make it work.
How can I solve this situation?
Thanks

Comment: Does the command work outside of Node.js? (i.e. when you run it in a terminal window)

Comment: Can you give us the output of `ls -l data`?

Comment: Yes the command run outside node.

Comment: The folder is empty and I have tried `sudo chmod -R 777 data/`

Comment: For testing purposes, try using a static string (with no variables like `process.env.PROFILE`) and make sure you are executing the script in the same folder where `data` is located.

Comment: @LucaPolito thanks, your answer lead me to find the solution to the problem. The string `lastBackupFile` had a trailing `\n` which it was hard to to spot.